# How to make changes in uninstallation process of project developed in c#.net

Tags: c#, batch-file, windows-installer, uninstallation

I developed a small project in c#.net. I want to create a file in windows or system32 folder. So that I create a setup of my project and add file to system32 and run my setup. it successfull works.
But Now the problem is , when I uninstall my project from add/remove program frm control panel that file is also been deleted from system32 or windows folder. I dont want that uninstallation process will delete that.

So I tried another thing, I use batch file for creating the file in windows folder and after that it runs my setup.msi file.
It works. but when i used some batch to exe converter for converting my batch to exe and add my setup.msi file in it , my batch file creates the file in windows folder but failed to run my setup.msi file.

software IExpress workes good in this case but problem with IExoress is , It does not Add Administrator manifest. And my batch file needs that, becouse it is creating file in windows Folder.

I have no experience. I am Fresher. Job less. So I am tring some freelancing work. this is my first.
So please give an answer with good example.

Thank you.
Salil Malek

Comment: What tool are you using to create your MSI?

Comment: You could add a file / a registry setting when your application starts. This way it would not be part of the installation process and would not get deleted during the de-installation.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, standard **uninstall** procedure MUST remove all files from the User's computer pertinent to that particular application (installed with setup/.msi) **except for User-created files** (e.g., documents, etc): for that type of User-created files there should be an option for User to decide if they should be deleted during uninstall.

Comment: Except that while one should avoid installing files to the SystemFolder, ICE09 validates that the permanent bit is set for every component marked for installation into the SystemFolder.

Comment: thank you Alex Bell.
but I need some more.
I cant create file from my proj.
I want to create a trial version of my proj. so any other solution. you can use it for 10 times. and then it stops. but after uninstalling and then reinstalling it gives again trial version for 10times. so any other solutions??

Comment: hey. Can I add and run an external exe file from setup file of my c# project??
I mean we can add files in setup. And it will past my that file as a action of it.
but can i run a file ?

I create a EXE file which creates a File in Windows folder. So my Setup.msi is able to run that exe??